# Add results of a function to a new row in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list `doms.uni` that contains 4 unique domain names. What I'm looking to do is iterate through the list and pass each domain to a function - `dom.security()` - that performs an API call.

The results are fed into a data.table object - `dt.dom` - with 10 columns per domain row.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(doms.uni)){
  dt.dom <- as.data.table(dom.security(doms.uni[i]))
}
```

The problem is that the function is only 'inserting' the last row of results. I'm at a complete loss here.

Current output:

```
> dt.dom
       dga_score perplexity  entropy securerank2 asn_score prefix_score rip_score fastflux     attack threat_type
    1:         0  0.5734945 2.235926    -6.36658 -1.861628    -1.847827 -2.262666    FALSE CryptoWall  Ransomware
```

What I'm expecting:

```
> dt.dom
   dga_score perplexity  entropy securerank2 asn_score prefix_score rip_score fastflux     attack threat_type
1:         0  0.5734945 2.235926    -6.36658 -1.861628    -1.847827 -5.262666    FALSE CryptoWall  Ransomware
2:         0  0.5734945 2.235926    -6.36658 -1.861628    -1.847827 -10.262666    FALSE CryptCrypt  Ransomware
3:         0  0.5734945 2.235926    -6.36658 -1.861628    -1.847827 -22.262666    FALSE BSCrypt  Ransomware
4:         0  0.5734945 2.235926    -6.36658 -1.861628    -1.847827 -33.262666    FALSE TeslaCrypt  Ransomware
```

Comment: Not to beg or anything, but feel free to +1 the answer.  ;-)

Comment: @MrMeritology Andrew isn't able to upvote yet. He needs at least a [reputation score of 15 for that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). But why didn't you upvote his question then? In that way you are helping him to reach that point sooner.

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example (what's `doms.uni`) and the *exact* desired output. Running a `for` loop `1:nrow(doms.uni)` is a very bad practice. Growing objects while doing so is even worse. Doing `as.data.table` in each loop is even worse. You are not making any use of the `data.table` package capabilities, but on the contrary.

Comment: `doms.uni` is a list with 4 character strings (domains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

doms <- rep(LETTERS, 10)

process_dom <- function(dom) {

  list(dname=dom,
       lname=tolower(dom),
       val=as.integer(charToRaw(dom)),
       vow=dom %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"))

}

# method 1 - bind big list

bd1 <- function() { rbindlist(lapply(doms, process_dom)) }

# method 2 - preallocate & set
# important to keep the modes/types the same
big_doms2 <- data.table(dname=rep(as.character(NA), length(doms)),
                        lname=rep(as.character(NA), length(doms)),
                        val=rep(as.integer(NA), length(doms)),
                        vow=rep(as.logical(NA), length(doms)))

bd2 <- function() {
  for (i in 1:length(doms)) {
    d <- process_dom(doms[i])
    big_doms2[i, (c("dname", "lname", "val", "vow")) := d]
  }
}

mb <- microbenchmark(bd1(), bd2())

mb

## Unit: milliseconds
##   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
##  bd1()  1.160419  1.344958  1.497937  1.440926  1.531688   3.879397   100  a 
##  bd2() 88.689616 93.445185 97.679849 96.609646 99.077425 126.626109   100   b
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, appreciate the help